# Permission denied trouble Laravel, in centos 7

Tags: php, laravel, centos7

I have two laravel project on vps centos 7 server. One of the project is running without a problem but when I try to change project. I am doing it in `httpd.conf` I change just project folder. `/var/www/html/new_project/public` but having error which is permission denied, but already gave chmod like I did it old project.

I can't run two project in a server or something else causing this error?

Comment: Where do you see this error? Is it when you run a shell command, or when you try to load a page in the browser? If the second, what errors do you find in the httpd error log in /var/log? You can certainly run two projects in one server.

Comment: try to load a page in browser. @Joni